# Roman Numeral Pronunciation

Tags: numerical-methods, convention, translation-request

I fully understand roman numerals.

I = 1

V = 5

X = 10

L = 50

C = 100

D = 500

M = 1000

Now I'll stop stating the obvious and ask my question.

5000 in Roman Numerals is **V** with a line on top of it.
(I can't type that). I just wanted to know how you would say it.

Ex. MCLI (1151) is pronounced: **emm see ell eye**

So how would 5000 be pronunced in roman numerals?

Comment: Vee overline? $\overline {V }$ is \$\overline {V}\$, btw.

Comment: Given a free choice, I would say "vee bar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Roman numerals were "pronounced".
For 5000, $\overline{V}$, the number is $\textit{quīnque milia}$, just as we would we five thousand.

Source: http://blogs.transparent.com/latin/one-to-a-million-in-latin-and-roman-numerals/

Comment: I think Zeke just wants to read the script aloud.  "Six thousand two hundred eighty four is written vee-bar emm cee cee ell ecks ecks ecks eye vee."